# Pegar o ultimo dados json no php

Tags: php, json

Galera segue o código abaixo  que lista todos. preciso apenas do ultimo dado latitude e longitude

```html
$conteudo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/0ozWRQqxiMnv5bqJzSUIMyUIIbMGrP5qu/message.json'));
foreach ($conteudo->response->feedMessageResponse->messages->message as $key) {
    print_r('Latitude: '.$key->latitude);
    echo ' - ';
    print_r('longitude: '.$key->longitude);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos usar a função `end()` que pega o último elemento de um array. Porem Temos um objeto, então antes temos que converter esse objeto para array. Para fazer isso basta passar um segundo parâmetro para a função `json_decode()` como `true`. Feito isso podemos pegar o último valor dessa forma:

```
$ultimo = end($conteudo['response']['feedMessageResponse']['messages']['message']);
```

agora basta imprimir o valor que você deseja.

```
echo 'Latitude: '.$ultimo['latitude'];
echo ' - ';
echo 'longitude: '.$ultimo['longitude'];
```

Segue o código completo

```
<?php

    $conteudo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/0ozWRQqxiMnv5bqJzSUIMyUIIbMGrP5qu/message.json'),true);

    $ultimo = end($conteudo['response']['feedMessageResponse']['messages']['message']);

    echo 'Latitude: '.$ultimo['latitude'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo 'longitude: '.$ultimo['longitude'];    
?>
```